# No component found with schema: jms

Tags: java, xml, jms, apache-camel, hornetq

I am working on a project where we decided to add some interaction using jms and hornetq as provider.
 
I am quite new to Camel so I ran into a problem some if you may refer as trivial. 
The goal was to initialize connection factory and add the jms component. However, as I understand it can't be done directly in the route configurator. So I created camel-config.xml and placed it to the resources/ directory.
 
I filled it in the following way:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>ConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The project doesn't use Spring so it was the only example of the xml I have found that doesn't make use of Spring. 
In the route configurator I use `routeBuilder.from("jms:queue:top").to("...");`

However, when I start the project it throws FailedToCreateEndpointException and states 
"No component found with schema: jms". 
I suppose that the xml file is simply not used but I just can't understand how to point to it. 
Looking forward to hearing any advice.

Comment: This actually *is* using Spring and, as Peter said, it needs to be bootstraped or replaced. But, before anything else, verify that you actually have camel-jms dependency added. This is the type of error you get when you miss the component on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The `<beans/>` XML is a Spring configuration that has to be bootstrapped in some way. You may have a look at the Tomcat ActiveMQ example found [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-activemq-tomcat), showing how to do that in a servlet environment. Have a special look at `web.xml`:

```
<!-- location of spring XML files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:broker.xml,
        classpath:camel-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring, which loads the XML files and start our application -->
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Of course, you could also use a Java only setup as follows:

```
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

 ModelCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
 context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
```